# Where can I find training data for dialects of Hindi?

Tags: computational-linguistics, corpora, dialects, resource-request, hindustani

I am working on a NLP project that aims at identifying different dialects of Hindi language. My über goal is to generate dialogs in once the program identifies which dialect is given.

I tried looking for Hindi Movie scripts (Bollywood movies) which have dialogs that are not pure Hindi. I could not find much training data. Can anyone suggest any techniques or resources? Would be of great help.

Comment: First of all, have a question, how could movie scripts tell you about dialect? isn't dialect mostly a phonological thing? how is it have anything to do with script? isn't the script is supposed to be the same for a language to be a "dialect"? Maybe go to India yourself if your budget allows?
or watch local TV shows that are known to be conducted in local dialect in those major districts that speak Hindi? or maybe make some random phone calls? lol

Comment: We are trying to distinguish dialects based on spellings.

Comment: @YingXiong: No, dialects are much more than phonological: they usually have distinct lexis, and sometimes distinct grammar. I can't make sense of your questions about movie scripts, unless it is that you are confusing "movie script" = "the text spoken in a move" with "script" = "writing system for a language".

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any central repository for all Bollywood scripts, and [The Internet Movie Script Database](http://www.imsdb.com/) does not host Bollywood movies at the moment. But the screenplay of individual movie are not hard to come by. The troublesome part is looking for screenplay one movie at a time. There are a few blogs run by keen amateurs that host a few titles each. Here are some examples:

- http://www.filmcompanion.in/scripts
- http://filmmakersfans.com/famous-bollywood-hindi-scripts-download/
- https://moifightclub.com/category/scripts/

Note that these screenplays are not in NLP-friendly formats. Let alone the effort of scraping PDF, the screenplay of newer movies are in a mix of Hindi and English.